# I need the most recent value in a GROUP BY - CASE expression

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to make a `CASE` expression in T-SQL that's in a `GROUP BY` clause, that's basically asking if there's a `a.id` THEN provide `b.name` associated with it (`where a.id = b.id`) .

What I have so far is: (Updated Query)

```
SELECT b.name, ...
    MAX(CASE
         WHEN a.id IS NOT NULL
         THEN b.name END) 
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
   ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY ...
```

Because it's T-SQL, the CASE has to be in a aggregate function or GROUP BY clause, which is why I included the `MAX`. However, without the GROUP BY clause, there would be 4 values. I need the most recent value as defined by a.datetime. How can I put that condition in the CASE statement?

Comment: You pick it up in your `FROM` clause using a `JOIN`?

Comment: You can't compare anything to `null`, not even `null` itself.
So right of the bat, you should change your `case` statement to `WHEN a.Id IS NOT NULL THEN...`.  However, your question is not very clear as it is, so you might want to add some more content.

Comment: You mean a case _expression_ in a group by _clause_.

Comment: You are trying to get the `MAX` of b.Name... you sure you want the top result if put in alphabetical order?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text!

Comment: @ZoharPeled since it's t-sql, I can't use `IS NOT NULL`.
@jarlh thanks, sorry about that ... edited ^
@justiceorjustus I am using `MAX` since it's a `GROUP BY`... T-SQL requires an aggregate of some sort

Comment: @PhilK that's just plain wrong. tsql supports `IS NOT NULL` just fine, and even the less readable `NOT IS NULL` .

Comment: @PhilK what do you mean?, of course you can use (and should use) `IS NOT NULL` in tsql

Comment: @Lamak *mind blown* it works. lol, was trying `IS NOT 'NULL'` prior. But yeah, it worked as `IS NOT NULL` (no ' ')

Comment: however changing `<> null` to `is not null` still didn't solve the issue :/

Comment: Phil, you've come here with a broken solution you've imagined to some problem, and you're asking us to fix the broken solution but there's nowhere near enough detail to do that. Please post the actual problem you have - trying to fix your broken solution is beating a dead horse. For example, If you want to "find all the rows in B that don't have a matching row in A", then that is what you should ask

Comment: @CaiusJard working on it. It's a big query that I need to clean a bit

Comment: @CaiusJard now, that's a good comment, hopefully the question gets updated

Comment: careful with doing that; often people delete some vital part thinking it's unimportant. if you can give some exmaples od data that is going in, and data that you expect to see out, then it'll help us verify solutions

Comment: So it turns out, since I'm doing a group by statement, I just need the most recent b.name associated with it. There's another field a.datetime that has that. I just need to put that in the CASE statement somehow

Comment: The question has been evolving a lot, you should add your last comment to the question too, because it changes the meaning completely

Comment: @Lamak it did evolve thanks to the help I got in this post, I found what the issue was, but it requires a new solution... I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: How you have b.name in the select and in a max.  What is the group b?  a.id cannot be null for that going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last edit changes quite a lot. You should use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  b.name, ...
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.id 
                                    ORDER BY b.DateColumn DESC)
    FROM ...
    LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
       ON b.id = a.id
)
SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN a.id IS NOT NULL 
            THEN b.name
        END
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: I see, so I have to use a CTE and create a row number, and there's no solution in the CASE statement, right?

Comment: what do you mean?, I am using a `CASE` expression, just not using an aggregation function

Comment: yes, I see it, I just meant like create a filter within the CASE expression that will narrow it down or select the most recent

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly(From now on try including the full query, table data\structure, input and desired output) , you can join them from the beggining and then just pick `MAX()` :

```
SELECT ....
       MAX(b.name)
FROM YourTable a
LEFT JOIN YourTable b
 ON(a.id = b.id)
...
GROUP BY ....
```

If there's a match, the name will be fetched. Otherwise - it will be `NULL` .

Comment: That was my initial try at it, however, it's providing a different name and not the actual one associated with the ID for some reason. I mean, I made an exclusive join for the name table and gave it it's own alias, but it's still not putting the right name.

Comment: that just doesn't make sense. It just means that the name you have in tableB isn't the name you want

Comment: That doesn't make sense. This query should work for what you explained. Please provide data, full query used, and show us what didn't work.

Comment: Starting to see my point, guys? This question needs serious revision before it can be answered because the OP doesn't even seem to understand what he means himself let alone express it in a meaningful way so it can be answered

Comment: Calm down ... I'll expand the question. Thanks everyone else ^